# My carousel doesn't work what is the problem?

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.5.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.5.0-dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css">   
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="bootstrap-4.5.0-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Reveal</title>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="myslideshow" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item mr-0 active">
            <img src="Reveal/assets/img/intro-carousel/1.jpg" alt="pic" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item mr-0">
            <img src="Reveal/assets/img/intro-carousel/2.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item mr-0">
            <img src="Reveal/assets/img/intro-carousel/3.jpg" alt="c" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item mr-0">
            <img src="Reveal/assets/img/intro-carousel/4.jpg" alt="c" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item mr-0">
            <img src="Reveal/assets/img/intro-carousel/5.jpg" alt="c" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My carousel doesn't work and I don't know what is the problem,even I copied codes from the main bootstrap site but again it doesn't work. my pictures will have be presented by browser but it doesn't slide.can anyone help me?

Comment: I used [standart bootstrap template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template) and added your codes. It worked. Just carousel very slow nearly 10 seconds. You can change with that js [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#carouseloptions)

Comment: yes man the problem was about CDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with BootstrapCDN (content delivery network).
I used that BootstrapCDN from  [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)

.

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Reveal</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="myslideshow" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item mr-0 active">
            <img src="Reveal/assets/img/intro-carousel/1.jpg" alt="pic" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item mr-0">
            <img src="Reveal/assets/img/intro-carousel/2.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item mr-0">
            <img src="Reveal/assets/img/intro-carousel/3.jpg" alt="c" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item mr-0">
            <img src="Reveal/assets/img/intro-carousel/4.jpg" alt="c" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item mr-0">
            <img src="Reveal/assets/img/intro-carousel/5.jpg" alt="c" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```